# linux conda install log4j-2.10.0 package issue

Tags: linux, installation, anaconda, log4j2, bioinformatics

I am new to conda environment. I am running the GATK package and it shows the error of missing Log4j-2 package from apache, so I downloaded the Log4j package and tried to install it so that I can run the script smoothly, however, there is an error.

```
download link:
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/logging/log4j/2.10.0/apache-log4j-2.10.0-bin.tar.gz

code:
conda install apache-log4j-2.10.0-bin.tar.gz

Error:

Fetching package metadata .................

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

- apache-log4j-2.10.0-bin.tar.gz

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/r/linux-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

Can anyone help me ? Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the directory with the tar.gz file to the searched channels:

```
conda install -c file://dir/to/tar/file apache-log4j
```

In your case:

```
conda install -c file:///home/ubuntu/src apache-log4j
```

Comment: same  error shown. I input conda install -c /home/ubuntu/src/apache-log4j-2.10.0-bin.tar.gz apache-log4j

Comment: No: `conda install -c file:///home/ubuntu/src/ apache-log4j`